# Overwrite chat back up Google drive

Tags: backup

I read that googlse drive only keeps the latest 7 days whats ap chat back up . And the older ones are over written.  Is this true

Answer (score 1):

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921
   `Your phone will store up to the last 7 days worth of local backup files (Google Drive will only have the most recent). If you wish to restore a local backup which is not the most recent, you will need to do the following:

Download a file manager. Here are some choices: File Managers and Explorers.
In the File Manager, navigate to sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases. If your data is not stored on the SD card, you may see internal storage or main storage instead of sdcard.
Rename the backup file you wish to restore from msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.1.db.crypt12 to msgstore.db.crypt12. It is possible that your earlier backup may have been on an earlier protocol, such as crypt9 or crypt10. Do not change the number of the crypt extension.
Uninstall WhatsApp.
Install WhatsApp.
Tap Restore when asked.    `

As far as I understand if you manually backup to google drive you will have everything but with auto backup only last 7 days.